# AsyncTaskLoader: deliverResult does not trigger call back to onLoadFinished if data has not changed

Tags: android, loader

I would like to clarify something about AsyncTaskLoader (and probably other loaders as well) that seems to be asked a lot but never answered. I have noticed that if I cache data in a Loader and try to avoid a reload of the data, a call to deliverResult will not trigger a callback to onLoadFinished, if the data passed has not change since the last time the loader provided the data.  This means that even though the Loader has a copy of the data, it does not provide it to the listener (the Activity).  This is clearly the case as show here in the LoaderInfo code:

```
if (mData != data || !mHaveData) {
    mData = data;
    mHaveData = true;
    if (mStarted) {
        callOnLoadFinished(loader, data);
    }
}
```

I think this is a really important to realize.  Many tutorials online indicate that one should cache data in the loader as an instance variable then check if it has been set in onStartLoad and set it in deliverResult. Example:

```
...
String[] mWeatherData = null;

@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
  if (mWeatherData != null) {
    deliverResult(mWeatherData);
  } else {
    mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    forceLoad();
  }
}
....

public void deliverResult(String[] data) {
  mWeatherData = data;
  super.deliverResult(data);
}
```

The expectation here is that the call to deliverResults in onStartLoading will deliver the data via the onFinishedLoading call back and avoid a call to loadInBackground when the loader already has the data cached.  However as show above this will not occur if the data has not changed and the Loader has already run.  This seems contrary to the point of Loaders.

If your Activity maintains data in a field that is not persisted by Android during a configuration change (such as a TextView) you would expect the Loader to provide that data via the callback after the config change.  There is no way to get the cached data from the LoaderInfo object so it remains up to the app to save the data itself, which I though was one of the important responsibilities of the Loader.  The fact that the LoaderManager does cache its own copy of data via the LoaderInfo makes this all the more bizarre to me.

Some people have proposed using restartLoader instead of initLoader as a solution but this also defeats the purpose of the caching the data (both in your implementation of the Loader and via the LoaderManager).  The only correct solution I have come up with is to pass a reference of the activity to the Loader and use the deliverResults method to pass the data in the Activity.  To avoid memory leaks this means maintaining a weak reference to the activity bla bla bla.  Even that does not answer the question: why does the LoaderManager maintain a cached copy of the data but not provide any way for the app to get it when it needs it (after config change or the like)?

Is there possibly another lifecycle event that causes the LoaderManager to callback to the listener with the cached data?

Comment: I had the same problem when activity pause (by pressing the home button) the onLoadFinished not called when the data not changes.